# How to make http request with nested loop

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-template

In my application, I have to send a HTTP request in a nested loop as I am showing below:

```
for(let i=1;i<Names.length;i++) {
    for(let k=1;k<Data.lenght;k++) {
        let url = hostPath + "/"+Names[i] + "/" + Data[i];
        this.http.get(url);
    }
}
```

I have done above requirement as the way described below:

```
for(let i=1;i<Names.length;i++) {
    Observable.from(Data).ConcatMap((data) => {
        let url = hostPath + "/" + Names[i] + "/" + data;
        this.http.get(url);
    }).subscribe(() => {})
}
```

I want to maintain the proper order with regards to the `Names` array (outer loop), but can send parallel request for the `Data` array (inner loop). I am very new to angular, Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: better to collect all data you need perform request on, and then make one request with it

Comment: @DanilGholtsman any suggestion how to do it?

Comment: Do you mean run all iteration requests from `Names` sequentially and all iteration requests from `Data` for a given name in parallel ?

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi yes, correct.

Comment: @HardRocker well, you need server side controller,which would work with array of your names & binded data (or array of objects look like `requestDataList = [ { name:"HardRocker", data: "somedata"}, {name:"Ghassen", data:"somedata"}, ... , {}]` )

Comment: and you make request to this controller with this `requestDataList`. it's kinda broad question, in case of how you implement it. because of idk, maybe you got no access to the server or you got some other circumstances to to loop there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this, one small catch is that you need to handle empty array with `defaultIfEmpty`. Following code handles that as well:

```
let allData$ = Names.map(name => Observable.forkJoin(
    Data.map(d => {
        const url = hostPath + '/' + name + '/' + d;
        return this.http.get(url);
    })).defaultIfEmpty([]);
);

Observable.forkJoin(allData$).defaultIfEmpty([]).subscribe();  
// You will get data in same order here
```

Comment: facing one problem, when any intermediate request failed , then subsequent request are getting cancelled. how to avoid it.
I have not added "defaultIfEmpty([]);" as it was showing error as method not available for Observable.


My application is Angular 2application.

Comment: That is easy to handle you can put a catch in your get call and handle the error there. For instance this line  return this.http.get(url).catch(error => Observable.of(undefined)).

Comment: Actually I tried to return Observable of empty array  as   catch(error => Observable.of([])), which worked for me.
Any difference if I return observable of undefined?

Comment: But the main issue I am facing is as number of requests are increasing, which is upto 1500, its failing with ERR: Unable to Load Resources:Insufficient Memory.

Comment: You can return whatever makes more sense to you whether undefined or empty array both are fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156538/discussion-between-deepak-sharma-and-hardrocker).

Answer (score 0):

A great tool to achieve your goal are JavaScript asynchronous functions. The proposed solution suggests two functions: the first sends the `Data` promises in parallel and the second sends the `Names` promises sequentially using the parallel `Data` ones:

```js
/**
 * Sends the Data promises in parallel and returns the promise
 * 
 * @param {string} param the name from the Names array
 * @param {array} array the Data array
 * @returns {promise}
 */
function processParallel(param, array) {
    return Promise.all(array.map((element) => {
        // make sure to call $http and hostPath correctly here because of
        // the function scope change
        let url = `${hostPath}/${param}/${element}`;
        return $http.get(url);
    }));
}

/**
 * Sends the Names promises sequentially
 * 
 * @param {array} firstArray the Names array
 * @param {array} secondArray the Data array
 */
async function processSequential(firstArray, secondArray) {
    for (let i = 0; i < firstArray.length; i++) {
        await processParallel(firstArray[i], secondArray);
    };
}
```

You can thus call them as follows:

```
processSequential(Names, Data);
```

You can test this solution in this simplified example:

```js
const hostPath = '/home';
function processParallel(param, array) {
    return Promise.all(array.map((element) => {
        let url = `${hostPath}/${param}/${element}`;
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                console.log(url);
                resolve();
            }, 500);
        });
    }));
}
async function processSequential(firstArray, secondArray) {
    for (let i = 0; i < firstArray.length; i++) {
        await processParallel(firstArray[i], secondArray);
    };
}
processSequential(['John', 'Sarra', 'Marie'], ['1', '2', '3']);
```

Hope this helps.